# PHP data handling

Tags: php, json

hi i have this data and i want to change something in it that i want to change using PHP the problem is i don't know how to access that specific data it is stored in a variable ill post my code below also i have labeled the data i want to change.

```
{
  "id" : "",
  "name" : "",
  "namePostfix" : "",
  "updatedTime" : "2016-11-29T16:35:31.189Z",
  "createdTime" : "2016-11-07T05:19:20.352Z",
  "clientId" : "",
  "url" : "",
  "impressionUrl" : "",
  "trafficSource" : {
    "id" : "",
    "name" : "",
    "postbackUrl" : null,
    "pixelRedirectUrl" : null,
    "type" : "CUSTOM",
    "predefinedType" : null
  },
  "country" : {
    "code" : "NZ",
    "name" : "New Zealand"
  },
  "costModel" : "CPA",
  "clickRedirectType" : "DOUBLE_HTML",
  "paths" : [ {
    "weight" : 100,
    "active" : true,
    "landers" : [ {
      "lander" : {
        "id" : "",
        "namePostfix" : "",
        "name" : ""
      },
      "weight" : 100
    } ],
    "offers" : [ {
      "offer" : {
        "id" : "",
        "name" : "",
        "namePostfix" : ""
      },
      "weight" : 100
    } ]
  } ],
  "pathsGroups" : [ {
    "condition" : {
      "country" : {
        "predicate" : "MUST_BE",
        "countryCodes" : [ "NZ" ]
      },
      "customVariableConditions" : [ {
        "predicate" : "MUST_NOT_BE",
        "index" : 0,
        "texts" : [ "[zone]", "Unknown", "unknown" ],
        "text" : "[zone]"
      }, null, {
        "predicate" : "MUST_NOT_BE",
        "index" : 2,
        "texts" : [ "Unknown", "[clickid]", "unknown" ],
        "text" : "Unknown"
      }, null, null, null, null, null, null, null ]
    },
    "paths" : [ {
      "weight" : 100,
      "active" : true,
      "landers" : [ {
        "lander" : {
          "id" : "",
          "namePostfix" : "",
          "name" : ""
        },
        "weight" : 100
      }, {
        "lander" : {
          "id" : "",
          "namePostfix" : "",
          "name" : ""
        },
        "weight" : 100
      } ],
      "offers" : [ {
        "offer" : {
          "id" : "",
          "name" : "",
          "namePostfix" : ""
        },
        "weight" : 100
      } ]
    } ],
    "active" : false //change this to true
  } ],
  "cpa" : 1.2,
  "revenueModel" : "RPA_AUTO",
  "redirectTarget" : "INLINE",
  "inlineFlow" : {
    "name" : "",
    "countries" : [ {
      "code" : "",
      "name" : ""
    } ],
    "conditionalPathsGroups" : [ {
      "conditions" : {
        "country" : {
          "predicate" : "MUST_BE",
          "countries" : [ {
            "code" : "",
            "name" : ""
          } ]
        },
        "customVariable" : {
          "values" : [ {
            "predicate" : "",
            "variableIndex" : 1,
            "variableValues" : 
          }, {
            "predicate" : "MUST_NOT_BE",
            "variableIndex" : 3,
            "variableValues" : 
          } ]
        }
      },
      "paths" : [ {
        "name" : "Path 1",
        "active" : true,
        "weight" : 100,
        "landers" : [ {
          "weight" : 100,
          "lander" : {
            "id" : "",
            "name" : "",
            "numberOfOffers" : 1,
            "url" : ""
          }
        }, {
          "weight" : 100,
          "lander" : {
            "id" : "",
            "name" : "",
            "numberOfOffers" : 1,
            "url" : ""
          }
        } ],
        "offers" : [ {
          "weight" : 100,
          "offer" : {
            "id" : "",
            "name" : "",
            "url" : "",
            "affiliateNetwork" : {
              "id" : ""
            }
          }
        } ],
        "offerRedirectMode" : "DOUBLE_HTML",
        "realtimeRoutingApiState" : "DISABLED"
      } ]
    } ],
    "defaultPaths" : [ {
      "name" : "Path 1",
      "active" : true,
      "weight" : 100,
      "landers" : [ {
        "weight" : 100,
        "lander" : {
          "id" : "",
          "name" : "",
          "numberOfOffers" : 1,
          "url" : ""
        }
      } ],
      "offers" : [ {
        "weight" : 100,
        "offer" : {
          "id" : "",
          "name" : "",
          "url" : "",
          "affiliateNetwork" : {
            "id" : ""
          }
        }
      } ],
      "offerRedirectMode" : "DOUBLE_HTML",
      "realtimeRoutingApiState" : "DISABLED"
    } ],
    "defaultOfferRedirectMode" : "DOUBLE_HTML"
  }
}
```

here is my code:

```
$wh = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($wh, CURLOPT_URL, "https://core.voluum.com/campaigns/" . $id);
            curl_setopt($wh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($wh, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


            $head = array();
            $head[] = "Cwauth-Token: " . $tok;
            curl_setopt($wh, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);

            $resulta = curl_exec($wh);
            if (curl_errno($wh)) {
                echo 'Error:' . curl_error($wh);
            }
            echo "Request:" . "<br>";
            echo '<pre>' . print_r($resulta, true) . '</pre>';
            $resulta->pathGroups->active='true';
```

i really dont know if what iam doing is right. someone help me please
tried using json_decode 
here is my code where i use json_decode:

```
$wh = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($wh, CURLOPT_URL, "https://core.voluum.com/campaigns/" . $id);
            curl_setopt($wh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($wh, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


            $head = array();
            $head[] = "Cwauth-Token: " . $tok;
            curl_setopt($wh, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);

            $resulta = curl_exec($wh);
            if (curl_errno($wh)) {
                echo 'Error:' . curl_error($wh);
            }
            echo "Request:" . "<br>";
            $campinfo = json_decode($resulta, true);
            echo '<pre>' . print_r($campinfo, TRUE) . '</pre>';
            foreach($campinfo['pathsGroups'] as $datacamp){
                echo $datacamp['active']=1;
```

yes i have change the value with this code but my problem is how will i put the value back to the $resulta variable i need all the data in one piece before i can submit to server.

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode()` ?

Comment: what error does that give you? also, remove the quote braces around `true`.

Comment: it doesn't give any error, ill update my post and add the part where i use json_decode give me sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$arr = json_decode($json);
$arr->pathsGroups[0]->active = 'true';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode() like:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);   // 2 parameter is true so that it returns an array instead of object
```

it will convert the json data into array and use it accordingly